# Swagger 2.0 + Jackson: @JsonIdentityInfo doesn't work

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

We are attempting to have Swagger 2.0.  Basically, it's great except it is ignoring the @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonIdentityReference annotations.

```
public class Source {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "name")
    @JsonProperty("sourceDefinitionName")
    private SourceDefinition sourceDefinition;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

Resulting in the Swagger schema output:

```
{
     "id": 0,
     "sourceDefinitionName": {
          "configuration": {},
          "driver": "string",
          "id": "string",
          "name": "string",
          "sourceType": "QUERY",
          "title": "string"
     }
}
```

You can see that it indeed reads the @JsonProperty annotation renaming the "sourceDefinition" to "sourceDefinitionName" but the value should just be a string.

Does anyone have any insight into this sort of problem with this integration?

Comment: And still not working. I've tried to use the JsonIdentityInfo annotation over the class type, over the attribute. I've also tried to use the JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference annotations and nothing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Source.class, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "SOURCE_DEF_NAME", referencedColumnName = "name", nullable = false,
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_sourceDefName"))
  private SourceDefinition sourceDefinition;

  @Column(name = "SOURCE_DEF_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String sourceDefinitionName;
```

Json identity is not working for me too. I have fond following workaround. see working example [json-sample](https://github.com/webcane/json-samples)